# OnTouch event is not called when Viewpager is empty

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touch-event

The Touch Event works fine when there is image in the ViewPager.
However, the Touch event doesn't work when there is no image / empty folder.

My app loads the images to the ViewPager depending on the user selected folder.

Code:

xml:

```
    <test.com.ExtendedViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="514dp"
        android:background="@drawable/no_image"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

As you can see, the ViewPager displays the default image when the folder/directory is empty.  However, the Touch event doesn't work.

```
public void LoadViewPager() {
    ImagePathList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (File file : listFile){
        ImagePathList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }        
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, ImagePathList));   //Custom ViewPager Adapter
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(LastItemPos);
```

Adapter:

```
    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(final View view, int position) {
        final Zoom_ScaleImageView imageView = new Zoom_ScaleImageView(activity);
        imageLoader.loadImage(AdapterImageList.get(position),  new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String path, View NoView, Bitmap bitmap) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageView, 0);   
            }
        });                 
        return imageView;
    }
```

How can I make the Touch event works in ViewPager when there is no image?

Thank you

Edit:
See my solution below...

Comment: How do you set the on touch listener?

Comment: Try to put your image in a LinearLayout, and implement the onTouchListener on the layout.

Comment: Touch event is in this class Zoom_ScaleImageView.  It is extremely long that's why I didn't include it.  I got it from one of the open source and modified it.  The reason I am using this open source class is because it has double tap to zoom.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution.  It may help someone else.  It may not be the best solution, but it is working for me.

Basically,
    I check to see if the arraylist is > 0 or not.
    If it is not > 0,
    then load the no image drawable.

```
public void LoadViewPager() {
    if(ImagePathList.size() > 0)       
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, ImagePathList)); 
    else
      {
      //load the drawable
         ImagePathList.add("drawable")
         mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, ImagePathList)); 
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might work if you change android:visibility="gone" to android:visibility="invisible" in the xml file. because if it is gone, it can not be touched.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not the case because I set it Visible in a condition programmatically.  The background image "no.image" does show up.  I changed it as your suggestion, but it is still the same result.  Thanks